# How can i parsed error message in job jenkins to slack message in channel?

Tags: ruby, jenkins, slack

How can i parsed error message in job jenkins to slack message in channel ?

i need to parsed only error message from console output job jenkins to slack channel. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this [slack notifier gem](https://github.com/jenkinsci/global-slack-notifier-plugin) and [slack plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin) by Jenkins organisation.

According to `README` you will need install it as plugin directly on Jenkins website, and setup message to send

Comment: how can i do it on job, not on pipeline?